# change the file name with a .bat file

Tags: batch-file

What I'm trying to do is take multiple files and remove the unnecessary data from the file name. The good thing is there all the same format using an "_" as a delimiter in the name. The format looks like this Report_16666_2023_01.csv. What I need is the second delimited data the rest can be removed so the file would look like this 16666.csv. Any help would be great. I would love to better understand how this works and any websites you can send me links so i can learn more would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  We expect some effort put forth before asking a question; per the close reasons, "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."  You need to attempt something, and if you are stuck, come back with a question.  Also, asking for links is off-topic as well, because "[q]uestions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or **favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: Please try and ask a proper question. Go through the rules and regulations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very similar to rene's answer, but only renames files that match `*_*_*_*.csv`.

```
for %F in (*_*_*_*.csv) do @for /f "tokens=2 eol=_ delims=_" %N in ("%F") do @ren "%F" "%N.csv"
```

---

Double up all percents as below to use in a batch file:

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*_*_*_*.csv) do for /f "tokens=2 eol=_ delims=_" %%N in ("%%F") do @ren "%%F" "%%N.csv"
```

Comment: I put that in a file called trim.bat in a folder with one of the csv files and it just flash on the screen I tried changing the ren to echo and the same thing. I'm obviously missing something. I thought maybe it was that I needed to have @echo on at the top but that didn't work either. I went to this website to try and understand better how this works. http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech.php

Comment: @fulltiltphil - Oops, I forgot a `*`, all fixed now

Comment: that works from the command prompt. So now I'll try and get it to work from a .bat file

Comment: I'm just not ab le to get this to work in a bat file. I've tried adding the extra %'s and changing the ren to echo. there has to be some tutorial that can tell me how to format these types of files.

Answer (score 0):

From the commandline this will work...

```
   for /f "delims=_ tokens=1-2,*" %a in ('dir *.csv /b') do ren "%a_%b_%c" "%b.csv"
```

replace the command `ren` with `echo` if something doesn't work and you need to debug.

For  better understanding of how things work: type `HELP` in the command prompt to see all available commands. All commands support `/?` as a parameter to explain what the command is doing. If you issue a `for \?` you'll find what /f does and how the options work. `dir \?` will reveal why I used `/b`